# Ionic ion-text-wrap: remove elipsis and go to next line for label

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

Hopefully this is a simple fix but I am very new to Ionic and I have searched through their docs and also a lot of posts on stack but cant seem to nail it.

So I have received a defect from the test team that a label I have which is

> Decision Details

is being presented as

> Decision..

across all platforms and devices.

I would like to be able to view the whole text or else the decisions part of it take to a new line instead of elipsis.

At the same time, I would like to keep the same formatting as the other labels that use `ion-text-wrap` are fine.

Here is some code:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap" class="bold">Decision </ion-label>
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap"> {{ excursion.excursionDecision }} </ion-label>

    <ion-label *ngIf="showCommentArray[i]" class="ion-text-wrap" class="decision" class="bold" button (click)="presentModal(i)">Decision Details</ion-label>
    <ion-label *ngIf="showCommentArray[i]" button (click)="presentModal(i)"
      ><ion-icon name="arrow-forward" class="commentsArrow"></ion-icon
    ></ion-label>

    <ion-label *ngIf="showCommentArray[i] === false"></ion-label>
    <ion-label *ngIf="showCommentArray[i] === false"></ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to remove the elipsis and ensure that label goes to the next line and displays fully?

Appreciate any help thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by adding CSS:

```
.decision {
white-space: pre-line;
font-weight: bold;
}
```